# Remove extra text (notepad++)

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert this:

```
LIVE | 139.59.101.223:1080 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 139.59.61.29:1080 | 0.77 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 91.122.46.56:9050 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 138.68.232.41:1080 | 0.23 | Unknow | Unknow |
```

to this:

```
139.59.101.223:1080
139.59.61.29:1080
91.122.46.56:9050
138.68.232.41:1080
```

How can I do that?

i want use in notepad++

Comment: They are IP addresses aren't they. There are lots of posts out there about how to match IPs.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat strict matching pattern:

```
pattern = (r'LIVE \| '
    r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5} \| '
    r'\d+\.?\d* \| '
    r'Unknow \| Unknow \|')

matches = [re.match(pattern, line)[1] for line in lines]
```

Comment: sorry , i want use in notepad++

Comment: So why did you put `python` tag?

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using regex...

```
_, ip, *_ = line.split('|')
ip = ip.strip()
```

In example...

```
>>> line = "LIVE | 139.59.101.223:1080 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |"
>>> _, ip, *_ = line.split('|')
>>> ip = ip.strip()
>>> print(ip)
139.59.101.223:1080
```

Answer (score 0):

press `ctrl + h` to call up replace dialog, regex below capture only the IP number text and discard evetything else

find : `.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+).*`

replace with : `\1`

select the regular expression radio button, then replace all

[image]

Comment: i use this regex but has a problem
this regex convert this

LIVE | 139.59.101.223:1080 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 139.59.61.29:1080 | 0.77 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 91.122.46.56:9050 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |
LIVE | 138.68.232.41:1080 | 0.23 | Unknow | Unknow |

to this 

9.59.101.223:1080
9.59.61.29:1080
0.122.46.56:9050
8.68.232.41:1080

2 number in start of everyline removed

Comment: my bad, check the revise regex

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a regex like
[`LIVE \| (.+?) \|.*`](https://regex101.com/r/vmTv7f/1) to capture the data you are looking for in a group and replace it with group 1 `\1`

**Explanation**

- Match `LIVE \|`
- Capture in a group any character 1 or more times no greedy `(.+?)` (This will contain your data)
- Match any character zero or more times `.*`

If you have this string:

`LIVE | 139.59.101.223:1080 | 0.8 | Unknow | Unknow |`

Group 1 will contain `139.59.101.223:1080`